# PHP $_GET is not populating with URL query parameters, from web browser

Tags: php, nginx, get, query-string

I'm running into a strange issue where the `$_GET` (and `$_REQUEST`) variable is empty, even though the parameters are being passed.

My PHP code:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo print_r($_REQUEST);
echo print_r($_GET);
```

Output:

```
/service/getAllOrders?sortBy=date_created&sortDir=desc
Array()
Array()
```

I'm using nginx and forwarding all requests to index.php. My configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  decaro.localhost;
    root       /Users/rweiss/Sites/decaro/LocalOrderWebsite;

   #access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default.access.log  main;

    location / {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
        include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        allow all;
    }

    location = /info {
        allow   127.0.0.1;
        deny    all;
        rewrite (.*) /.info.php;
    }

    error_page  404     /404.html;
    error_page  403     /403.html;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Are you using url rewriting?

Comment: Plus, why the need to echo a `print_r()`?

Comment: I guess he's using url rewriting, and you need to show us your .htaccess file

Comment: Did you tested same code on a different machine to make sure if it's a problem with the code or with your php/apache installation?

Answer (score 8):

The solution was to just pass the $query_string variable in nginx:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

Thanks for all of your help.

Ryan

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to print out :

```
 echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

This is the GET data that is inserted to the Super Global $_GET 
in addition , i think that you should call to your script using this link :

```
www.yourdomain.com/service/getAllOrders.php?sortBy=date_created&sortDir=desc
```

Pay attention to the .php..

See what is at you query string before checking the $_GET , try to print using

```
 echo print_r($_GET,1);
```

Comment: I tried to print out query string, but it is also empty, and the print_r($_GET,1) also has an empty array. I updated the question with my nginx configuration.

Comment: Did you try with the .php ? i also compare your Nginx Conf from         /etc/nginx/sites-enabled ( i hope its the same path ) . your root path should have root       /Users/rweiss/Sites/decaro/LocalOrderWebsite with a / at end